# Convert matrix of attributes to tree/graph

Tags: matrix, graph, tree

I'm looking to convert a matrix of attributes into a hierarchical tree or graph showing the most optimal subsets of commonality. See below image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSCaw.png

Is there a term for this process or a particular algorithm I should be researching?

Better yet is there any existing software package that could help me perform this kind of transformation?

Comment: what approach have you thought of taking? try something...

Comment: It's not at the implementation stage yet, there's still a lot of work to be done in building the initial matrix. I'm simply interested in knowing if there's a name for this kind of transformation or if it's an already well established algorithm before I set about reinventing the wheel.

Comment: we'll, i'm not an expert in this field - but Stack Overflow is all about programming - if you haven't done any research, tried something and ask for help... this site is not your target...

Comment: Well then can you suggest an alternative stack exchange site? I had considered posting in http://math.stackexchange.com/ but as I'm a programmer and not a mathematician I feel the responses garnered here would be more appropriate.

Also I don't see how it's relevant that I haven't attempted it yet? When the time comes I certainly will, but I'm discussing programming theory and asking a question as to whether or not this is an existing concept. My initial research has lead me to Similarity Matrices and Adjacency Matrices but neither seems to be suitable.